# Rendering Rails from tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have my form_tag set up as follows:

```
<% Rating.find(:all, :conditions => ["recommendation_id = ? and rating_set = ? and product_id = ?", rec.id, params[:rating_set_id], params[:product_id]]).each do |rate| %>
            <%= text_field_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][notes]", "#{rate.notes}", :id => "rec_note_text", :placeholder => 'Enter Notes..'%>
                <% end %>
```

This works when the find conditions are met, however before the form is submitted, the recommendation_id is not persisted to the DB, so this find method does not return anything, and this causes my form tag not to render. It only render when all conditions of the find are met. How can I render my form regardless is the find condition is met?

Comment: if you want to render the form even if your conditions not met, then whats the purpose of having conditions ? Do you meant to show it for nil ?

Comment: I guess your problem is that `text_field_tag` is not called in in the iteration, right?

Comment: plus you are doing recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][notes]", "#{rate.notes}"

When your conditions not met do you have the object of rec && rate ?

Comment: I dont want the user to get confused thinking there is no notes field. The conditions are there so that the form updates the correct record, and that works great, but before the form is submitted, those conditions are not met, which is whats causing the form_tag not to render.

Answer (score 1):

You are using view/controller in a wrong way.

You should define new partial called **_rating.html.erb**

in there your form_tag (please replace with valid values, I have just put as an example)

```
<%= text_field_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{id}][notes]", "#{notes}", :id => "rec_note_text", :placeholder => 'Enter Notes..'%>
```

then, wherever you are rendering that list of Ratings, put for example in **ratings/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render @ratings%>
```

and in Ratings_controller you should put:

```
define show
  @ratings = Ratings.find_all_with_conditions
end
```

and in model  Rating.rb you should put:

```
define self.find_all_with_conditions
  Rating..find(:all, :conditions => []) #put your logics here for finding all
end
```

I have just wrote just as an example how you should organize it, and I have not looked to put all valid parameters, I have put just for you to see how to organize you view.

I hope it will help.